# Anyone have success pushing AARs to (private) Bitbucket with Gradle?

Tags: android, git, ssh, bitbucket, aar

I've found some tutorials on how to upload to public Bitbucket repos using username + pw, but haven't had any success. I've published AARs locally to LocalRepository, but can't configure the uploadArchives command to actually push AARs to our private Bitbucket repo.

I've got git and ssh configured and can access the repository via terminal, but I can't figure out how to get gradle to be able to communicate with Bitbucket. Any suggestions or links?

I'm pretty sure I need to use wagon-git, but haven't had success yet:

http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html

The 2 most relevant blog posts I've found are probably these:

https://medium.com/@Mul0w/publish-with-gradle-on-bitbucket-1463236dc460#.f18eibtxt

http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/

Comment: have you found any solution

Comment: i have a answer about this at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207997/wagon-git-and-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207997/wagon-git-and-gradle) question. Hope it help